# How do I save jupyterlab's sidebar width, or set the default width？

Tags: jupyter-lab

I recently installed jupyterlab3, which has a lot of great plugins. But I found that I couldn't save its sidebar width Settings, which caused me to manually drag the sidebar to display the full filename every time I opened JupyterLab(even everytime i refresh).

I noticed related issues on github, but I did not find a solution.
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5314
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9269

I tried to change **--jp-sidebar-min-width** in the following two files, but it didn't work.

```
C:\Users\53082\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-@jupyterlab-theme-dark-extension-2.2.4-63a168783ea966530e80abb35a03d0d5e938d3df-integrity\node_modules\@jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\style\variables.css

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\style\variables.css
```

My jupyterlab version is 3.0.14
[cmd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLIae.png)

this is the default width
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7H1e.png)

This is the width that suits me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvrp0.png)

What should I do to fix my width or set the default width?

Comment: I know this pain. I hope that starting with 3.1 version we will be able to hide the last modified column properly (see my PR: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10100), but having the sidebar remember its width is a must for me as well.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10180

Comment: Thank you for your issue. I really hope this problem can be solved soon